# How editing timeline

Tags: timeline

I have created a animation sequence and now I want to optimize the time between key frames. Simple, I want to extend or reduce the number of frames between key frames.
The only way I have currently figured out, is to select all key frames after that and move them with 'G'. But if you have a long sequence, it is realy not easy to handle!

Is there no easy way to include empty space between key frames?

Comment: you can either scale or move the keys that are on the left or on the right of your cursor, what solution do you prefer?

Comment: There is time remapping, if you just want to change fps